# How can I hide a large number of columns in an excel spreadsheet using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using EPPlus version 3.1.3 to create a spreadsheet and I want to hide all of the columns from column L to column XFD and all the rows from the bottom most row to the end. I'm trying to hide the columns by using:

```
for (int i = 12; i <= 16384; i++)
{
     worksheet.Column(i).Hidden = true; 
}
```

This takes forever though for this loop to run. Does anyone know of an alternative way to hide a large amount of columns? I also have no idea how to hide the rows.

I'm wondering if there is another solution outside of EPPlus, but I really don't want to add another library to this.

Comment: worksheet.cells("L:XFD").Hidden=True ?

Comment: @SeanCheshire I don't know epplu but would it not be `worksheet.columns("L:XFD").Hidden=True` ?

Comment: according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368476/epplus-working-with-multiple-columns-by-index-rather-than-alphabetical-represe) EPPlus uses `cells` for every reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution for the columns.

I wanted to hide columns 10 to 16384 (last). The following Code did the trick and has a good performance.

```
//EPPlus 4.04 is used.

Dim col As ExcelColumn = osheet.Column(10)
col.ColumnMax = 16384
col.Hidden = True
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same for rows? I can't find a "RowMax" for ExcelRow.

Answer (score 2):

Does either of these work?

```
worksheet.columns("L:XFD").Hidden=True
```

or

```
worksheet.columns("12:16384").Hidden=True
```

(please forgive me if these are miles away as I don't know `EPPlus` too well)

---

**EDIT**

I think Sean Cheshire's comments answer your question?

```
worksheet.cells("L:XFD").Hidden=True
```

The reference he provided seems to confirm this: [EPPlus - Working with multiple columns by index rather than Alphabetical Representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368476/epplus-working-with-multiple-columns-by-index-rather-than-alphabetical-represe)

Comment: Unfortunately no. EPPlus does not appear to let you select multiple columns as far as I can tell.